# django loop over request post

Tags: jquery, django

I have a form and when submit it i send post data:

```
exset   349
exset   495
exset   344
reps    11
reps    22
reps    33
weight  1
weight  2
weight  3
```

in view i want to save it like this:

```
exset   349
reps    11
weight  1

exset   495
reps    22
weight  2

exset   344
reps    33
weight  3
```

but in database i have 3 rows with last data. Is it possible to make a loop to save all 3 portion of data?

I use jquery to send request to view:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $(".ex_set").each(function() {
        var array = $("input", this).serializeArray();
        //console.log(array);
        //alert(json.exset_id);
    });
});
```

Here is my view:

```
def TrackWkDay(request):

workout_log = Workout_log()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        workout_log.exset_id = request.POST.get('exset')
        workout_log.weight = request.POST.get('weight')
        workout_log.reps = request.POST.get('reps')
        workout_log.save()
        message = 'Data saved'
        returned = {'message':message}
        json = simplejson.dumps(returned)
        mimetype = 'application/json'
        return HttpResponse(json, mimetype)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

Comment: No input validation nor sanitization ?! Also, if you're going to send multiple values for the same POST key, you should make sure that `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;` else jQuery will be PHP-compliant instead of standard-compliant - which is what Django wants... Finally, try request.POST.getlist instead of request.POST.get.

Comment: Validation nor sanitization will be added later. Now I want to understand mechanizm of data saving.